# Electromagnetic waves how many polarizations for numberwaves?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, degrees-of-freedom

I'm reading about stationary waves in a cube with side of length $L$. The electric field is described from a vector $E$ where each component is of the type $sin(\frac{\pi}{L}n_{j}x_{j})$ and the author says that if I call $K=\frac{\pi}{L}(n_{1},n_{2},n_{3})$, where $n_{j}$ is natural, I have two polarizations for each $k$, "one for each orthogonal direction' Why?

Comment: Could you refer us to the book you are reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are free to choose our coordinate system. Thus, let's choose the $z$ direction to be parallel to the wave vector, $\vec k \parallel\vec z$. Since the electro-magnetic field is transverse in nature, we further know that the electric field is perpendicular to the wave vector, $\vec k \perp \vec E$. Thus, we know that $\vec E$ must oscillate in the $xy$-plane. Finally, any oscillation in a plane can be described by the projection onto two independent vectors. These are two polarisations. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much